# How to distribute tasks properly across multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a computationally intensive program that could benefit from a simple parallelization since each task in a list of tasks is independent of one another.

I'm not all that familiar with the theory that underlies computing in parallel and I can't seem to find a clear answer to my question which is:

**How do I distribute m tasks across n threads in a clean, canonical way?**

My solution to this would be to run "blocks" of processes to be handled, i.e. allocate the first n tasks in the list to the n threads available, then (and here I think it's fair to make the assumption that in my particular program all tasks will take roughly the same time) after that block has been completed, allocate the next n tasks and so on, and if the number of tasks is not divisible by n, take the remaining k < n tasks and execute them on k threads while the remaining n-k threads idle.

In C++ I'm sure I could accomplish this fairly easily with a for loop and the % operator. I know it's not the most efficient way to do it but I think the speedup from doing it "properly" (i.e. ensuring no threads idle) is negligible in my particular case.

Is this the right way to do it? Or is it perhaps possible, if I have a total m tasks to allocate m threads to the job and let the processor deal with distributing the tasks?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Don't have more active tasks (threds) than CPU cores available.

Comment: What kind of tasks are these? And how are they allocated? Just some ideas: As soon as a thread finishes, it could create/allocate the next task itself and continue. Or the tasks could be placed into a queue (std::list/std::deque), appropriately secured against race conditions, and as soon as a thread finishes a task, it takes the next one from the queue.

Comment: If each task takes approximately the same amount of time then thats a perfectly fine way to do it. If taks' lengths vary, you may have to give threads smaller task blocks and give a thread more when it is done.

Comment: "  I could accomplish this fairly easily with a for loop and the % operator" - modulo *what*? The`%` operator is not magic, it has to be applied to *something*. What is that "something" here?

Answer (score 1):

Before rolling this out by hand, see if your problem can take advantage of the facilities found in `<algorithm>`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

This way, you can take advantage of the execution policies, which, while implementation defined, attempt to find that ideal sweet-spot between CPU starving and idling without incurring in unnecessary wastes due to thread-related machinery or context switching. At the very least, it will spawn as many threads as can be physically mapped to the platform, and in more advanced cases profile itself while searching for that sweet spot.

Comment: Assuming your toolchain of choice has already implemented this, of course :)